# Navigation Drawer has wierd behaviour

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

So my situation is that i've implemented navigation drawer correctly (so to speak, it displays properly and calls out method (in a weird way but it triggers)) but it acts weird and I don't know what else to do but to ask u peeps !

Once i've started binding methods to drawer's menu items (options) i've begun to notice weird behavior. Let me explain by words first :

**Let this be dummy menu :**

[image: This is how menu looks in real app]

Ok so you see the order goes: home - history - favourite - logout

So far i've implemented history and favorite this is the behaviour i get :

1. If i call history it will open activity properly and display data
2. If i call favourite i will open HISTORY FIRST then FAVOURITE SECOND (i can see that because when i press back it closes favourite, opens history)
3. I've added a dummy activity as third option to menu (not displayed on pic) and i get the same behaviour but this time it opens History - Favourite - Dummy if i click on dummy activity.

One more thing before i post the code of how i implemented it.
Lets take 2 of mine activities and make real time example ( all in same ciclus).
1) From home page i try to use drawer and call out history/fav it works perfectly, i enter search i try to use drawer call out history/fav works perfeclty, i press back return to main activity (home) press drawer to open history/favourite and puuf it's not working anymore... any idea if it's connected or just an separate problem to solve?

**Implementation:**

```
final NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // set item as selected to persist highlight
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            // close drawer when item is tapped

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home: {
                    if (checkInternetConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "PROVJERA NETA  POVEZAN");
                        start_loader();
                    } else {
                        mEmptyStateTextView.setText("Cannot connect to network, please check your network status and try again.");
                        // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data

                    }
                }
                case R.id.nav_history: {
                    pozoviHistory(null);
                }
                case R.id.nav_favourite: {
                    pozoviFavorites();
                }

            }


            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
            // For example, swap UI fragments here

            return true;
        }
    }
);

mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
    new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            // Respond when the drawer's position changes
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Respond when the drawer is opened

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Respond when the drawer is closed
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            // Respond when the drawer motion state changes
        }
    }
);
```

****** EDIT ********

Okay so from the answer below adding the break; to each case resolved issue of opening everything. I've managed to find more symptoms causing drawer to act dumb.

So the action i'm doing that's causing drawer to act dumb is :
 - I've got inside activity a thread which makes http request and starts media player.
 - Once the thread is finished through the listener i've added i begin reproduction of media player
 - Once it initializes i inflate my layout with some layout that represents media player( could this be the issue of making drawer dumbs ? )
- Also slide right-to-left (for closing) is not working but clicking outside drawer (on activity layout) closes  it normally

This is how i inflate :

```
  DrawerLayout myLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.cili_test);
                View itemInfo1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player2, myLayout, true);
```

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
Check this link

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i've managed to implement it just that something is messing the normal flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `break;` in your switch case

Like this:

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_home: {
                if (checkInternetConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "PROVJERA NETA  POVEZAN");
                    start_loader();
                } else {
                    mEmptyStateTextView.setText("Cannot connect to network, please check your network status and try again.");
                    // Clear the adapter of previous earthquake data

                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_history: {
                pozoviHistory(null);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nav_favourite: {
                pozoviFavorites();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Okay so break statement resolved issue that it was opening everything instead of just option from the menu.

I've noticed one more symptom of when navigation drawer's menu items are not responding and it is  that ONCE it has stopped triggering methods it becomes dumb and doesn't react to slide-left for  closing the drawer (before it works all normally)